# How to add an IDirectSound to an IFilterGraph2?

Tags: c#, com, directshow, naudio, directshow.net

I've been Googling/StackOverflowing for days and can't figure this out.

I have a WPF project where I want to play videos on multiple screens simultaneously with separate audio systems. For playing video, we're using [WPFMediaKit](http://wpfmediakit.codeplex.com/), which relies on [DirectShow Lib .NET](http://sourceforge.net/projects/directshownet/). For other systems, we'd like to use something a little more modern, such as the Core Audio API via [NAudio](http://naudio.codeplex.com/). We control the environment and only have to support Windows 7 (may migrate to 8 in the future).

WPFMediaKit's `MediaUriElement` allows you to set its `AudioRenderer` but it exhibits issues because of the 31 character limit imposed by... DirectSound? I'm not entirely sure where the limitation comes from but it's a problem because all of our audio devices have very similar names (which most likely won't be unique within the space of 31 characters). So, the plan is to modify the source and allow it to take in a GUID representing a DirectSound device and change its behavior to look it up by that. The code that'll present the audio device endpoint list to the user will rely on NAudio's `MMDeviceEnumerator` from the Core Audio API.

I've gotten this far:

```
private static void DemonstrateTheIssue() {
    SpeechSynthesizer speech = new SpeechSynthesizer();
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    SpeechAudioFormatInfo synthFormat = new SpeechAudioFormatInfo(EncodingFormat.Pcm, 88200, 16, 1, 16000, 2, null);
    speech.SetOutputToAudioStream(stream, synthFormat);
    speech.Speak("This is a test. This is only a test.");
    stream.Position = 0;
    RawSourceWaveStream reader = new RawSourceWaveStream(stream, new WaveFormat());

    MMDeviceEnumerator coreAudioDeviceEnumerator = new MMDeviceEnumerator();
    MMDeviceCollection coreAudioAudioEndPoints = coreAudioDeviceEnumerator.EnumerateAudioEndPoints(DataFlow.Render, DeviceState.Active);
    MMDevice coreAudioSpdif = coreAudioAudioEndPoints.First(ep => ep.FriendlyName.Contains("S/PDIF")); // just an example. In the real application, would be selected by user and the GUID would be stored instead of the FriendlyName
    string spdifGuidValue = coreAudioSpdif.Properties[PropertyKeys.PKEY_AudioEndpoint_GUID].Value as string;
    Guid spdifGuid = Guid.Parse(spdifGuidValue);

    DirectSoundOut directSoundSpdif = new DirectSoundOut(spdifGuid);
    directSoundSpdif.Init(reader);
    directSoundSpdif.Play();
}
```

This code works. When I inspect NAudio's source of `DirectSoundOut`, I can see it calls `DirectSoundOut.DirectSoundCreate` from `dsound.dll`, which initializes an `IDirectSound` instance. I'm not entirely sure what I can do with that instance. So, going back to the other side of this puzzle...

Let's look at what WPFMediaKit does when I give it an `AudioRenderer` of `"Digital Audio (S/PDIF) (High De"`. Digging through the source, I eventually came across `AddFilterByName(IGraphBuilder graphBuilder, Guid deviceCategory, string friendlyName)` which eventually calls `AddFilterByDevice(IGraphBuilder graphBuilder, DsDevice device)`. Okay, so this uses its own wrapper class, `DsDevice`... which wraps `IMoniker` and a few other things, including some properties from an `IPropertyBag` attached to the `IMoniker` instance. The last line of C# code I see before my trail vanishes into COM calls this: `filterGraph.AddSourceFilterForMoniker(device.Mon, null, device.Name, out filter)`. `filterGraph` is an `IFilterGraph2` instance and `device.Name` returns `"FriendlyName"` from the moniker's property bag.

I feel like I'm close but I just can't connect the dots. How can I take an `IDirectSound` instance and tell the `filterGraph` to play audio on it? Do I need to get a moniker for the `IDirectSound`? If so, how? Is there another method I'm unaware of? Or... can I create/compose/get a reference to my own filter and tell the `filterGraph` about it? If so, how would I go about doing that?

Please answer this question like I'm a child -- this stuff is really over my head.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DirectSound and DirectShow are two different APIs. There is no direct adding of DirectSound objects into DirectShow filter graphs and hence your inability to do impossible.

There are two ways to address the problem: you either insist that you already hold an `IDirectSound` interface pointer and you want to use it within DirectShow. In this case you have to implement a custom audio renderer filter, which will be backed by this DirectSound interface and your renderer will forward all audio to the device of your interest. You don't really want to go this way. In particular, you won't be able to implement this in C# only.

And the second way is to find an existing DirectShow audio renderer, which is using the device of your interest. Then use it and it will play through the same DirectSound device, just not exactly the pointer you had on your hands in first place.

More details on the second approach. DirectShow has a special category where all audio renderers are listed: [`CLSID_AudioRendererCategory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375655%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Enumerating filters there, you enumerate instances of [`DirectSound Renderer Filter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375473%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) created for every existing device.

> This filter acts as a wrapper for an audio device. To enumerate the
>   audio devices available on the user's system, use the ICreateDevEnum
>   interface with the audio renderer category
>   (CLSID_AudioRendererCategory). For each audio device, the audio
>   renderer category contains two filter instances. One of these
>   corresponds to the DirectSound Renderer, and the other corresponds to
>   the Audio Renderer (WaveOut) filter. The DirectSound instance has the
>   friendly name "DirectSound: DeviceName," where DeviceName is the name
>   of the device. The WaveOut instance has the friendly name DeviceName.

You can find the right device there, and you then you can use this filter as a regular audio renderer (that is, you add it to your graph, you connect it there). The filter does not however expose `IDirectSound` pointer it is using internally.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer. The second way interests me but I've already went down that path with no luck -- perhaps I missed something. WPFMediaKit goes through DirectShowLib, using `CreateDevEnum` and `IEnumMoniker` to find the device by name. But, like I said - my names aren't unique within 31 characters. I've tried to use the enumerated device's moniker's property bag to find something to correlate a Core Audio device and failed; I don't know what key to look for and `IPropertyBag` sure does make it difficult to find a list of all keys. Do you have any other advice?

Comment: In DirectShow, DirectSound device names are not trimmed at 32nd character. Do you have them trimmed on DirectSound side? Or, the names are exactly the same at all?

Comment: The name returned from the `IMoniker` is trimmed at the 32nd character, i.e. `"Digital Audio (S/PDIF) (High De"` is returned from `theDevice.GetPropBagValue("FriendlyName")`. `GetPropBagValue` reaches into the `IMoniker`'s `IPropertyBag` for its values. `theDevice` is an instance of `DirectShowLib.DsDevice`. `DsDevice`'s [source](http://sourceforge.net/projects/directshownet/files/DirectShowNET/v2.1/) can be found in `DsUtils.cs`. Perhaps I'm asking the property bag for the wrong key? ... No, the names do differ; I don't want to store the name though - it changes when devices get plugged in.

Comment: Clipped names like "Speakers (Realtek High Definiti" are those devices backed by WaveOut API, not DirectSound. DirectSound device names are not clipped, and the names themselves are like "DirectSound: Realtek Digital Output (Realtek High Definition Audio)". That is, when it comes to listing devices implemented through DirectSound Audio Renderer, you should be able to have a full name to compare to

Comment: Well... that greatly simplifies things! I had the wrong device chosen because it was the first S/PDIF one enumerated so my modified LINQ code grabbed it, `allDevices[4]`. If I had known `allDevices` had basically the same end point listed twice (`allDevices[6]` in this case)... I wouldn't have hit this roadblock. Ugh! Well, thanks to you, I found the actual device I want and its `DSGuid` from the property bag matches up exactly with the GUID returned from NAudio's Core Audio API. So, I don't even need to "fuzzy match" based on name. Awesome! Thanks a ton!

Comment: Is the `GUID` {79376820-07D0-11CF-A24D-0020AFD79767}, by any chance?

Comment: Nope. `Digital Audio (S/PDIF) (High Definition Audio Device) ... {0.0.0.00000000}.{acd7ef82-ba4b-4274-a9da-7536b6455c4d}`. I did find your `GUID` in the registry, though... under `"DirectSound Audio Renderer"`; it also points to `quartz.dll`. Elsewhere I see it listed as the `"Default DirectSound Device"`. So, the `GUID` I pasted is unique, yeah? Google doesn't seem to know anything about it. Your `GUID` also shows up if I ask the property bag for the `"CLSID"`.

Comment: I am afraid this GUID refers to device that NAudio obtains through WASAPI API, and supposedly it can use it to play to directly, without DirectShow. Which might be still OK with you. For a DirectShow filter, I don't think you can obtain this information from moniker or instance, and name comparison will be necessary (if you still want DirectShow).

Comment: Got'cha. I think I'll be okay; I just tested it with 2 other devices (3.5mm jack from onboard audio & video card's DisplayPort audio channel) and it seemed reliable to use the `GUID` provided  by NAudio and match it up against the devices returned by DirectShowLib. All unique, no collisions.